# Hyperparameter-free method for Moving Average/ Exponential smoothing?

Tags: python, hyperparameter, exponential-smoothing

I want to find hyperparameter-free method for Moving Average/ Exponential smoothing. Is there any related paper or python code?

S(t)= **alpha** * F(t) + **(1-alpha)** * S(t-1)

Any methods can avoid the choice of alpha? Or automatically update the alpha?

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Question about the weighting factor of Exponential Weighted Moving Average (EWMA/EMA)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413707/).

Comment: I think most of the exponential smoothing functions will estimate the $\alpha$ for you. Otherwise it is extremely easy to write your own code for an exponential smoother for a given $\alpha$; estimation of $\alpha$ is the hard part. Try out function `ets` from the `forecast` package in R. It estimates $\alpha$ and even facilitates (optionally) automated selection between different versions of exponential smoothing methods.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. I will try it now.

Comment: you can use pd.ewm(alpha=#your choice#)